# Using button in one component to render another component in main (App) component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am trying to display/hide one component which is ItemMain and which is imported to the main App component using button in another component which is NavLogoNew. I tried to do this in many different ways but it looks like the button doesn't know if it's clicked, when I change true/false manually it works. In web I found a lot of stuff about situations when only two components are involved, but nothing like this. My code:

App

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { tsPropertySignature } from '@babel/types';
import { statement } from '@babel/template';

import NavBar from './../Components/Navigation/NavBar/NavBar.js';
import ItemMain from './../Components/Item/ItemMain/ItemMain.js';
import ItemList from './../Components/Item/ItemList/ItemList.js';
import NavButtonTop from './../Components/Navigation/NavButton/NavButtonTop/NavButtonTop.js';
import NavLogoNew from './../Components/Navigation/NavButton/NavButtonNew/NavLogoNew.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.visible
    })
  }     

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        {this.state.visible ? <ItemMain /> : null}
        <ItemList />
        <NavButtonTop name='UP'/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

NavLogoNew:

```
import React from 'react';
import './NavLogoNew.css';
import ItemMain from './../../../Item/ItemMain/ItemMain.js'


class NavLogoNew extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (    
            <button 
                className='NavLogoNew'
                onClick={this.props.click}  
            >
                {this.props.name}  
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export default NavLogoNew;
```

Comment: You'r not using the `NavLogoNew` in your main app, you just import it. And for better readability, change the `click` prop name to `onClick`, then use it like so: `<NavLogoNew name="Some Name" onClick={this.handleClick}/>`

Comment: Your handleClick function is lacking somehing   handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.visible
    })
  }

Comment: AfikDeri - import is the remainder of trying doing it differnt way. <NavLogoNew /> is part of <NavBar /> so I can't import it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your handleClick function is lacking something
use `!this.state.visible`  so change from the below

```
handleClick(){
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.visible
    })
  }
```

to

```
 handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.state.visible
    })
  }
```

pass the handleClick function to the NavLogoNew as follows

`<NavLogoNew onClick = {this.handleClick} />`

inside of the NavLogoNew component you should invoke it as follows

```
class NavLogoNew extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (    
            <button 
                className='NavLogoNew'
                onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}  
            >
                {this.props.name}  
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: "of course it with the assumption that you pass it as a prop to the NaveLogoNewcomponent" like this? onClick={this.props.handleClick}

Comment: When passing it from the App component to the NaveLogoNewComponent it should be like this `onClick={this.handleClick}` without the props

Comment: I have made edits to the post you should test it now. If you properly follow the instructions you should have it working. some of the things you will want to be sure of is if you after clicking on the button in the NavLogoNew component the state of the parent(App.js) changes are. I am supposing you don't perform any binding inside of the NavLogo component.